# How to bind module and theme together in magento?

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.7

I have created a theme named "levdes" and a different module "laven_main",
here is my code for app/code/local/laven/main/etc/config.xml..

```
            <?xml version="1.0" ?>
            <config>
                <modules>
                    <Laven_Main>
                        <version>0.1.0</version>
                    </Laven_Main>
                </modules>
                <global>
                    <models>
                        <laven_main>
                            <class>Laven_Main_Model</class>
                        </laven_main>
                    </models>
                    <blocks>
                        <laven_main>
                            <class>Laven_Main_Block</class>
                        </laven_main>
                    </blocks>
                    <helpers>
                        <laven_main>
                            <class>Laven_Main_Helper</class>
                        </laven_main>
                    </helpers>
                </global>

                <frontend>
                    <routers>
                        <laven_main>
                            <use>standard</use>
                            <args>
                                <module>Laven_Main</module>
                                <frontName>main</frontName>
                            </args>
                        </laven_main>
                    </routers>
                    <layout>
                        <updates>
                            <laven_main module="laven_main">
                                <file>laven_main.xml</file>
                            </laven_main>
                        </updates>
                    </layout>

                </frontend>
            </config>
```

and this is my theme file at location app/design/frontend/default/levdes/layout/local.xml

```
            <layout version="0.1.0">
                <default>
            <!--        <reference name="top.links" >
                        <action method="addLink" translate="label title">
                            <label>Main</label>
                            <url>main</url> 
                            <title>main view</title>
                            <prepare/>
                            <urlParams/>
                            <position>1</position>
                        </action>        
                    </reference>-->

                    <reference name="head">
                        <action method="addCss"><stylesheet>css/main_style.css</stylesheet></action>
                        <action method="addCss"><stylesheet>css/style.css</stylesheet></action> 
                        <action method="addCss"><stylesheet>css/popup.css</stylesheet></action> 
                        <action method="addJs"><script>levdes/popup.js</script></action>
                        <action method="addJs"><script>levdes/validatesubmit.js</script></action>
                    </reference>

                    <reference name="top">
                        <remove name="" />
                    </reference>
                </default>
                <cms_index_index>            
                    <reference name="top">
                        <remove name="top.links" />
                        <remove name="top.forms" />
                    </reference>
                </cms_index_index>
                <cms_page_view>
                    <reference name="top">
                        <remove name="top.links" />
                        <remove name="top.forms" />
                    </reference>
                </cms_page_view>
            </layout>
```

Now here is what i want to do, i want to use "laven_main" module's helper in my "levdes" theme's template file.

Is this possible? i have seen this this in a bluescale theme which is available on 
magento-connect. And yes i am using magento 1.7 .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use it just like any other helper:

```
Mage::helper('laven_main')->doSomething();
```

I see no reason to why this shouldn't work. Or am I missing something?